# Call a vector in managed C++ from C#

Tags: c#, c++, vector, managed-c++

I want to have a vector that has a number of independent variables. In my C++ header(.h) I defined it like this:

```
private:
    // Static data structure holding independent variables
    static vector<double>* indVariables;
```

And in my .cpp file it is defined the same and then I'm going to have to use this vector in some other function like this:

```
static vector<double>* indVariables;

void fun(int m, int n)
{
    for (i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    {
        ai = indVariables[i];

        temp = exp(-n * (ai - 8.0));
    }
} /* fun */
```

Now in C# I want to copy a set of numbers to this vector and call it back to C++ something like this:

```
var matu = new double[]{ 8.0, 8.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0};
myCppClass.indVariables = matu;
```

How can I do it?

The first problem is because it is private I don't see it in C#. Do I have to make it public or are there other ways? And then how can I assign values to this vector?

Comment: Visibility has nothing to do with your problems. `std::vector` does not exist in C#. You should write a function that converts a `std::vector` to a C# `List` with C++/CLI code.

Comment: but how can I write the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that it is private does present an issue, but, making it public won't just solve your problem I think.  C# doesn't know what an std::vector is, as Richard said.  I don't know much about the structure of your code, what its doing, how its being used, etc, but, if all you need is to assign a list/array of numbers to the vector, you could use a List<> in your C# code and wrap the assignment of the vector in something like this in your CLI project/file:

```
void Assign(Collections::Generic::List<double>^ l )
{
    IndVariables->clear();
    for each (double i in l)
    {  
        IndVariables->push_back(i);
    }
}
```

Then in your C# program, you'd write (or however you've declared your List<>):

`yourCppClass.Assign(new List<double>(){0.0, 42.0, 8.0});`

You could also add additional wrapper methods to manipulate or access the vector.  Again, this may or may not be suitable depending on the structure of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the [Collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh700103.aspx) documentation for C++/CX:

> In a Visual C++ component extensions (C++/CX) program, you can make
>   free use of Standard Template Library (STL) containers, or any other
>   user-defined collection type. However, when you pass collections back
>   and forth across the Windows Runtime application binary interface
>   (ABI)—for example, to a XAML control or to a JavaScript client—you
>   must use Windows Runtime collection types.

So, you can use STL containers as much as you like internally, but you won't be able to pass them between runtime components as they don't cross ABI boundaries.

A quick fix would be to use the `Vector` class available at the `Platform::Collections` namespace through `<collection.h>`.

Change your header declaration to:

```
public:
        static Vector<Double>^ IndVariables;
```

Your C# component needs to change as well:

```
var matu = new Double[] { 8.0, 8.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0};
myCppClass.IndVariables = matu;
```

This is untested code, so syntax errors or other minor issues should be present in the snippets above.

Comment: but the problem is if I add `<collection.h>` All other cli arrays I defined in my code will get confused and I get a huge amount of errors. I cant change all my array definitions to `cli::array` because it's a big work

Comment: Well, I don't know how your code looks like. You didn't provide enough information so I thought you were working with C++/CX Runtime Components. I never used C++/CLI so I can't help you much. Perhaps prepending the namespace to each array declaration fixes this problem.